# Facebook like comment/likes update on page without page referesh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, facebook, counter

I am going to make social network like ASP.net page where I need to update individual post with new likes count increment, new comments added and posted time update till now just like facebook does.

Additionally I would like a countdown for each post. Once some one clicks a post countdown starts and post should be disappeared once countdown reaches to zero.

I am using Gridview to show posts.

Any help/directions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read asp.net signalR technology which is being used for real time web applications.

Comment: I knew it, I wanted to know about best solution to do this. I ended up using SignalR. Thanks